# How to inspect variable in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Say I have a code block that looks something like this...

```
$(function(){
    var Foo = "Thing";
    var Bar = "Other Thing";
    var Bag = new Widget({name: "Some Thing", color: "Purple"});
});
```

Is there a way to inspect or retrieve those variables/objects in the Chrome Console?  I guess I'm probably trying to use the Chrome Console as too much of a REPL, but I'm curious as to if it's possible.

--**Edit**: Sorry, I should have included more information.  I know I could add breakpoints or include a debugger call.  I'm more interested in seeing the variables/object *after* everything has ran to completion.

Comment: Find the code under the sources tab and stick a breakpoint in.

Comment: Put 'debugger;' as a code statement where you want Chrome to break. Remember to remove it again though!

Comment: 'console.log(Foo);' is another option.

Comment: Unless you log what you want to see to a file / server / console at the time the code is executing, then no, you can't do this. 'Run to completion' implies the code has finished running, meaning garbage collection etc, meaning there's no guarantee anything you want to see would still be in memory even if you could work out how to access it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible because those vars are local to the anonymous function.

You could temporarily do the following to inspect the values inside the function:

```
var Foo;    

$(function(){
    Foo = "Thing";
    var Bar = "Other Thing";
    var Bag = new Widget({name: "Some Thing", color: "Purple});
});
```

From here you can access `Foo` and see what value is inside.

Answer (score 1):

The variables are scoped to the function, which means they *cannot* be accessed outside it unless they are explicitly passed out. Here are some options I can think of:

1. You could declare variables of the same name in an outer scope, such as the `window`. Be careful, because if those variable names are used in other functions, they will all use the same "global" copy now and everything could break.
2. You could add a "variable-collector" statement just before the final return of an anonymous function:

   ```
   var collector = [];

   $(function () {
      var Foo = "Thing",
         Bar = "Other Thing",
         Bag = new Widget({name: "Some Thing", color: "Purple"});
      collector.push({"anonymousfunction1": {Foo: Foo, Bar: Bar, Bag: Bag}});
      return something;
   });
   ```

   Then at the end of execution, you can inspect everything in the `collector` variable all you like. I made `collector` an array since I figured you might have multiple anonymous functions you want to learn about, or the function could be called multiple times (though it looks to me like a jQuery `ready` event, you never know).
3. Just log the values to the console. This works in Chrome and Firefox (press F12) and may work in later versions of IE:

   ```
   $(function () {
      var Foo = "Thing",
         Bar = "Other Thing",
         Bag = new Widget({name: "Some Thing", color: "Purple"});
      console.log("Foo", Foo, "Bar", Bar, "Bag", Bag);
      return something;
   });
   ```